# SwiftUI & requestReview() – review popup not displaying

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, storekit

I am building an app with SwiftUI and would like to use **requestReview()** to display a review request popup. However, the popup is not displaying. From what I understand from the documentation, when the app is in development mode, the popup should display every time.

I've tested the app in the Xcode simulator and on a real device, I'm using Xcode 14.1. and the app builds without issue. (I'm also a SwiftUI newbie, I think I must be missing something obvious).

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit
    
struct DetailView: View {
        @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview
        @AppStorage("AppUsedCount") private var appUsedCount: Int = 0

        var body: some View {
            VStack {...}.onAppear{
                let updatedAppUsedCount: Int = appUsedCount + 1
                UserDefaults.standard.set(updatedAppUsedCount, forKey: "AppUsedCount")
                if (appUsedCount > 5){
                requestReview()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tested without the IF statement, but still no popup. **appUsedCount** updates as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same issue (iOS 16). It works when my application is in test, but no longer works when it is on the app store

Comment: Same here. It works while in simulator but not when in App Store. iOS 16.4. Has anyone found a fix?

Comment: Same here. It works in sample project Apple provides but not working when I migrate the simple code into my project. I have to revert to use the previous function:
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
        }